# NSURLConnection is not building connection using AFNetworking/CocoaPods due to incompatibility [Old version of iOS]

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocoapods, afnetworking, ios6.1

First of all, let me tell you that I'm using xcode `4.6.3` and `iOS 6.1`. I have been trying to build connection using `AFNetworking` or `CocoaPods`. it throws errors due to backward compatibility issues. Current error is `xctest/xctest.h` Is there any way out to this problem? I'm highly confused on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What version of AFNetworking you are using -

- AFNetworking 3.0 is the latest major release of AFNetworking, a delightful networking library for iOS & Mac OS X. To keep this library maintainable moving forward, 3.0 removes all support for the now deprecated NSURLConnection based APIs.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide

I hope this will help.